# How do you do two-way binding use variables?

Tags: ember.js

When a create a view from an object, it seems that when I change a property in the object, the view's property also changes.  If I change the property in the view, the change is not reflected in the object.  I thought two-way bindings were the default behavior.  Am I missing something?

```
WidgetClass = Ember.Object.extend
  address: 'widget address'
  create_view: ->
    # console.log this.name
    view = Ember.View.create
      someobj: this
      addressBinding: 'someobj.address'
      template: Ember.Handlebars.compile '{{address}}'

    return view

TextWidget = WidgetClass.create()

view = TextWidget.create_view()

view.append()

view.set 'address', 'new new address'
console.log (view.get 'address')
console.log (TextWidget.get 'address') # I am expecting this output to be 'new new address'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rkitamura/2zsUX/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When applying bindings and then testing them immediately, you need to force the Ember run loop to catch up. Try adding `Ember.run.sync()` before  `view.set 'address', 'new new address'`. Your `setTimeout()` call should no longer be needed.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried adding Ember.run.sync() and the bindings worked as expected.

Comment: Glad to help. If you're all set, please mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to use setPath in this case.  Two-way binding works perfectly.

The following code works.

```
view.setPath 'someobj.address', 'new new address'
console.log (TextWidget.get 'address')  # this outputs 'new new address' correctly
```